# How can i send and receive Hashmap from Webservice with Soap on Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, hashmap

This is my code:

```
public class PostSoap extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, String>, Void, HashMap<String, String> >{

    private String Tag= "PostSoap";
    final static String NAMESPACE = "http://wwyw.unimportant.com/";
    final static String METHOD_NAME = "unimportant";
    final static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://wwyw.adsdsad.com/unimportan";

    final static String URL = "http://unimportant:80/Service.asmx";

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(
            HashMap<String, String>... params) {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("obj",params[0]);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        Log.i(Tag,"soapenv..");
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        Log.i(Tag,"httptransport");

        try { aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);  }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); return null; }

        try { return ""+?????????;}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); return null; }

    }

     protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<bool,String> dyr) {
        if (dyr == null) { Toast.makeText(        , "error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return; } // 

        try { Toast.makeText(         , " "+dyr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }catch(Exception e){ } // 
    }
}
```

I know there are too many fail in this code. I want to send to request as a `HashMap` and also want to receive as a `HashMap`. How can I do it. I need more advice about this. 
Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the HashMap you got as input to add those key/values to SoapObject. After you recieve the response from the server, you need to parse the result according to the soap method's output format and fill them into a new HashMap or to an ArrayList object(depends on your needs) you create. If the server side of the application you create belongs to you, you can return a string which is formatted as XML or JSON. That would make it easier to parse into an object.

Answer (score 2):

**HashMap** is serializable by itself,in case all Key and Value objects are serializable and in your case key and value objects are String objects. So you can serialize your HashMap to a byte array as follows:

```
 HashMap<String, String> hashMap; //reference to the HashMap to be serialized

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(hashMap);
        byte[] hashMapAsByteArray = bos.toByteArray(); //HashMap serialized to a  byte[] array
        oos.close();
```

You can convert this byte array to text with Base64 encoding and then embed it in a SOAP message.

Answer (score 0):

You may create JSON array from your hashmap, and send that JSON data to other side.